# how to force java swing gui to update on this snippet

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

What I want from the following minimum working example is to change its radio button's text twice in a small time interval after clicking on it. i.e., when I click on the button, I want to immediately change its text to "1" and after 3 seconds to change its text again to "2".

```
public class Example extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Example() {
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jRadioButton1.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(137, 137, 137)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1).addContainerGap(242, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(126, 126, 126)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1).addContainerGap(153, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }

    private void jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        jRadioButton1.setText("1");
        //repaint();
        try { Thread.sleep(3000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        jRadioButton1.setText("2");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Example().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
}
```

The above obviously doesn't work.

I know that I should use repaint() or SwingUtilities.invokeLater() or maybe a new thread in some way, but I didn't manage yet to achieve the desired result with any combination of the them.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). `Thread.sleep()` blocks the event dispatch thread.

Comment: hire some efficient guy in Odesk or freelance, they know and they will do for you:)

Comment: i think you should read this, also : http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=291

Comment: @kiheru thank you very much, it works properly. If you wish post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping in the event dispatch thread blocks it and prevents drawing from happening as you have found out. It also makes the rest of the UI unresponsive for the time, so it's in the list of things you should never do.

The standard way to run delayed, or repeated action in swing applications is using a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). It runs the action properly in the event dispatch thread, so that you also don't need to pay special attention to thread safety. Using a `Timer` your button action becomes:

```
private void jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    jRadioButton1.setText("1");
    Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jRadioButton1.setText("2");
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change this

```
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
```

to

```
public javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
```

Then. You may write this class

```
public class Updater extends Thread {

    private Example e ;

    public Updater(Example e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public void run(){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            e.jRadioButton1.setText("2");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex){          
        }

    }

}
```

Now here in this method.

```
private void jRadioButton1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        jRadioButton1.setText("1");

        new Updater(this).start();
}
```

Comment: No, no. Swing is [not thread safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Accessing swing components (calling `setText()` in this case) should not be done outside the event dispatch thread.